# Control Loop Within Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I am attempting to control a loop I have within a loop. What I would like to do is display all post and have a custom post type inserted every 3 post. So it would be like this "post post post CPT post post post cpt..." I accomplished this by doing this

```
global $loop_counter;
$loop_counter = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
?>

// DO STUFF

<?php $loop_counter++; ?>

if ( $loop_counter%3 == 0 ) { 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'testimony',
    );
    $testimony = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $testimony->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $testimony ->have_posts() ) {
            $testimony->the_post();
            ?>

            //LOOP WITHIN LOOP

        } } 
    } END loop count if
```

?>

I slimmed down the code a bit but this should be enough. Now this is working like I want with one issue. The inner loop keeps repeating as long as the main loop has posts. I want the stop looping through the inner loop as soon as we are out of posts to display. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more like this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'testimony',
);
$testimony = new WP_Query($args);

if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); 
    if ( 0 !== $wp_query->current_post 
      && 0 === $wp_query->current_post%3 
      && $testimony->have_posts() 
    ) {
        $testimony->the_post();
        echo 'inner-loop';
        the_title();
        echo 'inner-loop';
        echo '<br>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    the_title(); 
    echo $wp_query->current_post;
    echo '<br>';
  }
}
```

You don't need the loop counter. There is a counter built into `WP_Query`, and you don't need to be running that `$testimony` query at every iteration of the outer loop.

The `the_post` method will increment the Loop by one, so at each iteration the inner loop runs that, `echo`s content and moves on.

There is obviously some debugging code in there. You can edit that out and replace it whatever you want.

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I have tried this several different ways with no luck. The simplist version was copy and paste the code and that retrieved only testimony posts. I was not calling $testimony outside of the inner loop before.

Comment: I know you weren't pulling the `$testimony` outside the Loop but why would you run it inside? The parameters don't change. The code works fine when I run it. The problem must have something to with the context, but I am not sure what.

Comment: Are you using your above within another loop or is this the whole loop?

Comment: This is the whole thing. The outer Loop depends upon the main query, just as your original code does. There is no inner Loop technically but it does walk through the `$testimony` Loop nonetheless because `$testimony->the_post();` runs every third post of that outer Loop. It should be a drop-in replacement for the code you posted. Also, I made a small edit to the function.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I just cant get it to work. This is a Genesis Child theme but I removed the loop and am attempting to get this custom loop to work. It is now calling on both loops but the testimony are displaying randomly  http://awesomescreenshot.com/04e1iet157 as you can see it is loading in a pattern 12122(repeated).